# Warning after mount a component in jest, test was not wrapper in the act

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hello I am writing test for a component and and I mount the component successfully. It gives me warning like

```
  console.error src/setupTests.js:17
    Warning: An update to ReactFinalForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at 
        in ReactFinalForm (at SalesTaxForm.component.js:53)
        in div (at Modal.component.js:41)
        in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Fade))
        in ForwardRef(Fade) (at Modal.component.js:40)
        in TrapFocus (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
        in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
        in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
        in ForwardRef(Modal) (at Modal.component.js:27)
        in Component (at SalesTaxForm.component.js:52)
        in SalesTaxForm (at salesTaxForm.test.js:36)
        in I18nextProvider (at salesTaxForm.test.js:35)
        in Provider (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent
```

Below is the my code:

**Component.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../../../i18n';
import SalesTaxForm from './SalesTaxForm.component';
import taxTypes from '../../../mockData/taxTypes.json';
import configureStore from '../../../setUpMockStore';

const initialState = {};

const initialRecord = {
    id: 194,
    taxRate: 1.29,
    taxType: 5,
    taxNo: "87681 1522 RT0001",
    startDate: new Date(2011, 10, 30),
    endDate: new Date(2035, 10, 30)
};

const store = configureStore(initialState);
jest.mock('../../../store');

let wrapper;
const open = true;
const record = initialRecord;
const reloadData = jest.fn();
const setOpen = jest.fn(() => { });
const taxTypesMock = taxTypes;

const mountComponent = () => {
    return mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
                <SalesTaxForm open={open} record={record} reloadData={reloadData}
                    setOpen={setOpen} taxTypes={taxTypesMock} />
            </I18nextProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
};


describe('SalesTaxForm', () => {
    it('should render the salesTaxForm', async () => {
        wrapper = mountComponent();
    });
});
```

**Componnet.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';
import createDecorator from 'final-form-calculate';
import Modal from '../../../components/UI/Modal/Modal.component';
import { defaultStyles } from '../../../commonStyles';
import { salesTaxOperations } from '../../../store/salesTaxes';
import validate from '../../../services/validation';
import Footer from '../../UI/Tab/Footer/Footer.component';
import { labels, schema } from './validationHandler';
import SalesTaxFields from './SalesTaxFields.component';
import styles from './SalesTaxForm.styles';

let taxTypesList = [];

const calculator = createDecorator({
  field: 'taxType',
  updates: {
    taxNo: val => {
      const indx = taxTypesList.findIndex(el => el.id === val);

      if (indx > -1) {
        return taxTypesList[indx].taxNo;
      }
    },
  },
});

const SalesTaxForm = ({ open, record, reloadData, setOpen, taxTypes }) => {
  const classes = styles();
  const applyDefaultStyle = defaultStyles();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  taxTypesList = taxTypes;

  async function saveHandler(data) {
    await dispatch(salesTaxOperations.updateSalesTaxData(data));
    reloadData();
    setOpen(false);
  }

  const closeHandler = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Modal title={t('SALESTAX_EDITOR')} open={open} showBtns={false}>
      <Form
        onSubmit={saveHandler}
        initialValues={record}
        decorators={[calculator]}
        validate={values => validate(schema, values, labels)}
        render={({ form, handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
              <div
                className={clsx(
                  classes.container,
                  classes.modalWidth,
                  classes.modalContainer,
                  applyDefaultStyle.modalinnergrid
                )}
              >
                <SalesTaxFields
                  classes={classes}
                  record={record}
                  taxTypes={taxTypes}
                />
                <Footer
                  closeHandler={closeHandler}
                  saveHandler={form.submit}
                  customStyle={classes.footer}
                />
              </div>
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
};

SalesTaxForm.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  record: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  reloadData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setOpen: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  taxTypes: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default SalesTaxForm;
```

In my code there is validate function is asynchronous that is causing the problem. Anyone can help in the resolve this problem ? Thanks in advance.